# Django ORM "filter" method produces SQL query without quotes

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-orm

I am building an app with Django relying on several PosgreSQL databases which I do not manage, let's call them database **A** and database **B**. For each database, I've used `python manage.py inspectdb` to build my `models.py` files.

I am trying to use Django ORM to perform the following query (*significantly simplified here*), `to_date` being a `datetime.datetime` object:

```
sample = my_model_in_B.objects\
    .filter(a_column=instance_of_a_model_in_A.name)\
        .exclude(another_column='Useless things')\
            .filter(a_column_with_dates__lte=to_date)
```

My issue is that it produces the following SQL query:

```
SELECT "myschema"."mytable"."a_column", "myschema"."mytable"."another_column" from "myschema"."mytable"
WHERE "myschema"."mytable"."a_column" = Here is the name of instance_of_a_model_in_A
AND "myschema"."mytable"."a_column_with_dates" <= 2020-02-03
AND NOT ("myschema"."mytable"."another_column" = Useless things
AND "myschema"."mytable"."another_column" IS NOT NULL))
```

In other terms, my issue is that **the Django ORM does not automatically add quotes where I need them**. I don't understand what I did wrong. I don't know if that matters but note that:

- I use Django 2.2. and my database **B** is POSTGRESQL 8 only,
- All the columns that I use correspond to `CharField` in my models, except *a_column_with_dates* which corresponds to a `DateField`.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I found this issue https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17612, but it 10 years old and was closed as invalid pointing to the link in docs where mentioned that you should manually escape such a things, because underlying database drivers may be the cause of issue, not django. But the link is also broken for now.

Comment: @Som-1 yes I might have found something helpful for you, please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, my initial question was wrongly worded and misleading. I was assuming that `QuerySet.query` (that I used to get the above SQL code) was supposed to return the valid SQL query behind Django ORM, but it isn't. It just aims at providing a basic representation of the query, nonetheless, [from a comment made on the official Django project website](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17741#comment:1):

> Django never actually interpolates the parameters: it sends the query
> and the parameters separately to the database adapter, which performs
> the appropriate operations.

Indeed, from the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api):

> The query parameter to QuerySet exists so that specialized query subclasses can reconstruct internal query state. The value of the parameter is an opaque representation of that query state and is not part of a public API.